# 'mysql' Recognized by cmd but not PowerShell?

Tags: mysql, powershell, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to run a very simple login script through powershell.

I have already added the default directory "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin" to the PATH variable. Now I was able to call mysql from command line prompt.

However when I tried to run the same script from PowerShell it showed that " The name 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file......"

My computer is running on Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: Is there a "PATH" that needs to be established?

Comment: Already established. And as I mentioned, the first thing I did was to add the bin directory to $PATH

Answer (score 4):

So as I am reading about powershell now a days and I find this interesting and wanted to know answer myself, on some googling here is what I found:

Considering that you are using  similar command as given below to fire the Mysql

> `PS C:\Program Files\mysql\MySQL Server 5.7\bin> mysql`

*Here is the full version of error that you should be getting :*

> mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the     path is correct
>   and try again. At line:1 char:1+ mysql
>   + ~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [],     CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command mysql was not found, but     does
>   exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does  not load
>   commands from the current location by default. If you      trust this
>   command, instead type: ".\mysql". See "get-he lp
>   about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

*If we see the Suggestion part it says **Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default**. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\mysql".*

So try using `.\mysql` instead of just `mysql` after setting the current directory to `C:\Program Files\mysql\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>` but this might lead you to another error which most probably will say :

> ```
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (usingpassword: NO)
> ```

which you can than resolve changing the syntax to `mysql -u root -p`

So it looks like kinda security thing that powersehll is imposing.

Source:[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/4lexcx/cant_get_mysql_to_work_on_powershell/)

**Note:** Try running `$env:Path` in powershell to see if the path is correctly set.